# Image indexing in sqlite database

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, indexing, fingerprint

I'm implementing finger print authentication using external device Secugen. In order to store the captured fingerprint i'm using byte array.

If i use normal search option it will take around 5-6 seconds to fetch the details from the local sqlite database.

I wanted to use indexing for this byte array in order to perform faster search option ?

Is it possible to make indexing for byte array or
Is there are any other methods to make faster search option of image ?

Comment: You really want to compare fingerprint by checking equality between byte array representation ? Read doc about fingerprint matching before ...

Answer (score 0):

You can make indexing like below code:-

```
CREATE INDEX byte_array_tag ON TABLE_NAME(byte_array_column_name);
```